# complex mysql query count from 2 table and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 tables inbound,outbound two tables have same structure

inbound

```
id | site_id | ip (bigint) | date
 1 | 1       | 12345678890 | 20140123
 2 | 1       | 12341234000 | 20140123
```

outbound

```
id | site_id | ip          | date
 1 | 1       | 12345678890 | 20140123
 2 | 1       | 12341234000 | 20140124
 3 | 1       | 12341234000 | 20140124
```

my input is only site_id i want to combine inbound and outbound tables and get result as

```
inbound_unique_ip_count |  outbound_unique_ip_count | date
                      2 |                         1 | 20140123
              0 or null |                         1 | 20140124
```

i think group by date should work?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
select date, COUNT(distinct(a.inbound_unique_ip_count) ) as `inbound_unique_ip_count`, 
COUNT(distinct (outbound_unique_ip_count )) as `outbound_unique_ip_count` 
from inbound a JOIN outbound b on a.site_id=b.site_id 
group by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct i.ip) AS inbound_unique_ip_count,
       COUNT(distinct o.ip) AS outbound_unique_ip_count,
       date
FROM inbound AS i
JOIN outbound AS o USING (site_id, date)
WHERE i.site_id = :site_id
GROUP BY date
```

This will only work properly if both tables have all the dates and the input `site_id`. If either table can be missing some of these, you need a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, which MySQL doesn't support. If you search SO for this, you should be able to find workarounds, I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: i did read in some site that left join union right join can give result as full outer join
from the above query i tried this `SELECT COUNT(distinct i.ip) AS inbound_unique_ip_count,
       COUNT(distinct o.ip) AS outbound_unique_ip_count,
       date
FROM inbound AS i
LEFT JOIN outbound AS o USING (site_id, date)
UNION
SELECT COUNT(distinct i.ip) AS inbound_unique_ip_count,
       COUNT(distinct o.ip) AS outbound_unique_ip_count,
       date
FROM inbound AS i
RIGHT JOIN outbound AS o USING (site_id, date)


WHERE site_id =1
GROUP BY date` but getting duplicate column date

Comment: [full outer join in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql)

Comment: You shouldn't get duplicates, since `UNION` should merge them. Can you make a sqlfiddle?